# Reference request for generic smoothness

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Consider the following: Suppose that $K$ is a perfect field, $V$ and $W$ are integral $K$-varieties, $V \to W$ is a dominant morphism, and the function field of $V$ is a separable extension of the function field of $W$. Then there is a dense open subvariety $U$ of $V$ such that $U \to W$ is smooth.

I would like a reference for this. I need this for something, and I have a proof, but I think this should be very well known so it's probably silly to write out a proof.

Vakil's notes give a proof in characteristic zero, but he doesn't give a citation. I have seen a sketch of a proof on mathoverflow, but no citation.

I apologize if this is a silly question. I'm doing some algebraic geometry without having any real background in the subject. I think this might be so well-known that you wouldn't need a citation for an algebraic geometry paper, but it's going to be used in a model theory paper, so I want to give references for basically everything from algebraic geometry that we use.

Comment: this fact is true in more general context.extending a property from generic point(function field) of an integral variety is called "spreading out". and you can do this for smoothness. a reference could be EGA IV_4 theorem 8.10.5

Comment: @ali are sure about the reference you give? I mean that EGA IV_4 starts at section 16 of chapter IV, so that there is no way theorem 8.10.1 can be there...  It is clear that EGA IV_4 contains the result though.

Comment: Certainly you didn't mean to write $U\to W$ smooth, but $V\times_W U\to U$ smooth.

Comment: @Denis-CharlesCisinski you are right. I made a mistake reading form a table.the right reference is EGA IV_4 theorem 17.7.8

Comment: A "user-friendly" reference is Poonen's "Rational points on varieties", a large part of which is something like a "reader's guide" to EGA. It contains in particular a helpful table collecting which properties of morphisms of schemes satisfy base change/descent/spreading out and where in EGA this is proven. EGA IV_4 Proposition 17.7.8(ii) is indeed the right reference for this result.

Comment: This seems very much like what I was doing. My method was to show that the generic fiber of $V \to W$ is generically smooth and then spread it out, using various parts of the "spreading out" theorem in Poonen's book (which is indeed very useful for someone like me). I'll take a look at EGA and see if this makes it more efficient. I suppose that generic smoothness of the generic fiber is basically trivial to someone who knows these things.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar I did mean $U \to W$, just that the restriction of $V \to W$ to $U$ is smooth.

Comment: I think spreading out is actually not relevant here. First, the openness of the smooth locus on the base is something you can cite from Liu's book or the stacks project. However, this open locus can of course be empty. What you are trying to show is that it is non-empty by showing that the generic point is contained in it. Thus, all you really have to argue is that the generic fibre of your morphism $V\to W$ is smooth (which has nothing to do with spreading out) and cite the relevant openness result.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Let me see if I understand what you are saying. Let $f$ be the morphism $V \to W$. The set of points in $V$ at which $f$ is smooth is open, so it is enough to show that $f$ is smooth at some point, we want to show it is smooth at the generic point of $V$. Let $L$ be the function field of $W$ and $f_L : V_L \to \mathrm{Spec} L$ be the generic fiber of $f$. I know that $f_L$ is smooth at the generic point of $V_L$ and I suppose that the generic point of $V_L$ is also the generic point of $V$. I don't see why this shows that $f$ is smooth at the generic point of $V$.

Comment: I also don't think that the generic fiber of $V \to W$ is actually smooth. I think we could take $V$ to be $W \times X$ for some non-smooth $K$-variety $X$ and $W \times X \to W$ to be the projection, then every fiber should have singularities. (I could be wrong about this, my handle on generic fibers is shaky at best.)

Comment: @ErikWalsberg I am still puzzled by your formulation. Are you not asking for the existence of a dense open $U\subset W$ such that $V\to W$ is smooth *over* $U$? If so, let $U$ be the locus of points in $W$ over which $V\to W$ is smooth. This is open. Let $V_U$ be the inverse image of $U$ along $V\to W$. If $U$ is non-empty, then it contains the generic point of $U$ (hence $V$). Base-changing along the inclusion of the generic point you end up again with a smooth morphism, because smoothness is stable under base-change. Conversely, if $U$ contains the generic point, then it is non-empty...tbc

Comment: @ErikWalsberg ...Your example $V=W\times X$ shows that the statement you seek is false in general (unless I am misunderstanding what you are asking for). Indeed, every geometric fibre of $W\times X\to W$ is indeed non-smooth. In particular, there is no dense open of $W$ over which this morphism is smooth. (The inverse image of $U\subset W$ would simply be $U\times X$...)

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar I want the positive characteristic version of Prop 3.1 from Vakil's notes https://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/0506-216/216class5152.pdf

Comment: So in the product example I would do the following (in characteristic zero): let $X'$ be the smooth locus of $X$ and $W'$ be the smooth locus of $W$, and let $U = W' \times X'$. Then $W' \times X'$ should be dense in $W \times X$ and the restriction of the projection to $W' \times X'$ should be smooth (I think).

Comment: @ErikWalsberg Ok. As you are allowed to replace $W$ *and $V$* by dense open subschemes (to prove your desired statement), we may and do assume that both $V$ and $W$ are nonsingular (as $V$ and $W$ are integral).  Then, by your generic separability condition, it is indeed true that the generic fibre of $V\to W$ is smooth.

Comment: @ArianJavanpeykar I think basically you proved the theorem that you can spread out smoothness!and I think OP is not familliar with the language of schemes. There is a more elementry way to prove generic smoothness in the shaferovich book basic algebraic geometry

Comment: There is a typo: $U$ is an open of $V$, not of $W$. The result follows directly from Tags [07ND](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07ND) and [00TB](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00TB).

Comment: Ah. That's why some people got confused.

Comment: Yes, that’s what confused me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, thanks everyone, but in the end I found a good reference. I will post it here as this might be useful for someone else.

The following is (a special case of) Corollary 5.4.3 in Mumford and Oda's Algebraic Geometry II: Suppose that $V$ and $W$ are integral $K$-varieties, $W$ is regular, and $f : V \to W$ is a dominant morphism. Then $f$ is smooth on a dense open subset of $V$ if and only if the function field of $V$ is a separable extension of the function field of $W$. The result in the book is written for schemes.